# mysql select into dumpfile create file with garbage code when the select contains non-english character(utf8)

Tags: mysql, windows

I am using Mysql select into dumpfile to dump data into a file.

```
select data from table1 into dumpfile "c:\xxxx"
```

where XXXX is non-English character(utf8 character), however the outcome file name in the Windows directory becomes strange garbage code. Is there any way I can keep the non-English
XXXX(utf8 character) in the file name but not become strange character？

Comment: Check `@@character_set_filesystem`.

Comment: How can I changed the @@character_set_filesystem to UTF8?

Comment: seems not working too.

Comment: I found it is the problem in Windows Server 2012. In Ubuntu, no problem exist.

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 you cannot set `@@character_set_filesystem` variable value to `'UTF8'`. It should be `'binary'` AFAIR. PS. Do not use non-A chars in filenames, rename them in the filesystem out of MySQL if needed really.